# Launching Jmeter from python and retrieving information while it is running

Tags: python, jmeter

I have a Jmeter script which at Step 1: it creates an account with accountId and then Step 2: does manipulations on that account which takes about 30 min .

I have written a python code with 2 threads, in one thread it calls that Jmeter script using:

```
  subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Thread actually runs and calls my jmeter script and it runs to end. But I want to retrieve the account ID as soon as it is created in thread1, and step 1, and monitor it using other commands in thread2 (while 1st thread is running Jmeter script).  Even though I have a post Bean process which prints the accountId to console, I don't get that until Jmeter has completed its 2nd Step.
I dont want to write the account ID in a text file and have my 2nd thread in python read from it (thats really not a good way to do it), is there any other way to get that account Id in step1 as soon as it is created?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out existing solutions, i.e. [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool which is Python-based wrapper for JMeter and a several more tools providing unified way of configuring and launching tests and producing results in the same format. In case of JMeter you will have possibility to execute multiple tests in parallel

You will be able to view the progress using console-based UI in the same terminal window:

[image: Taurus Running Test]

See [Taurus: A New Star in the Test Automation Tools Constellation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation) article for more information on Taurus installation and usage.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working like this:

```
def subCmdJmeter (self,cmd):
    with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, shell=True, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
        for line in p.stdout:
            print(line, end='')  # process line here

    if p.returncode != 0:
        raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, p.args)
```